# Base 8 to hexadecimal conversion

Tags: hex, octal

I would just like to confirm the following answer.

703710<sub>8</sub>.

8 does not form part of the number. Converting this to hexadecimal I get the answer ABCDE. Is this correct? If so what is the purpose of the subscript / base 8 which is written slightly below the number 703710.

Comment: @Cœur as you please mate

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way of converting octal to hex is through binary: octal digits correspond to three binary digits, while hex digits correspond to four. Convert the number to binary, regroup by four-bit nibbles, and then convert to hex.

The number converted to binary looks like this:

```
111 000 011 111 001 000
7   0   3   7   1   0
```

Regroup by nibbles and add leading zeros for conversion to hex:

```
0011 1000 0111 1100 1000
```

Now you can easily convert the number using a lookup table.

Comment: Thank you so much for your edit and answer so base 8 means that it is an octal number....am i right? So I first would have to convert 703710 to Octal? And from octal to hexadeciaml. In other words the correct answer is NOT 'ABCDE' but rather 387C8....am i right?

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee The `703710` is already in octal, so your new answer `387C8` is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The subscript indicates what base the number is *already written in*, in this case 8, so it's octal.

So 703710<sub>8</sub> is saying that the number is `7 * 8^5 + 0 * 8^4 + 3 * 8^3 + 7 * 8^2 + 1 * 8^1 + 0 * 8^0`, or 231368 in base 10.

IOW, 703710<sub>8</sub> = 231368<sub>10</sub> = 387C8<sub>16</sub>.

ABCDE (by which you mean ABCDE<sub>16</sub>, or `0xABCDE`), would be the right answer if the original number were written in base 10, because 703710<sub>10</sub> = ABCDE<sub>16</sub>.

Comment: Thank you! I think Im getting it. So IOW a number say 512 base 10 would = 200 in hexadecimal am i right? Thank you sooo much for taking the time to answer my question much appreciated

Comment: Yep, 512 base 10 is 200 base 16.